# How to identify two matrices are congruent when they are not symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It seems that most textbooks of Linear Algebra only mention **Sylvester Theorem** that tells us how to identify matrices are congruent when they are symmetric.
What happened if **nonsymmetric**? Is there any theorem or criterion that can be used to identify if two matrices are congruent when they are not symmetric?

Comment: Can you define congruency of matrices?

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are congruent if there exist an  invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{T}AP=B$. @AniruddhAgarwal

Comment: Someone [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2976548) the same question recently on this site. For $T$-congruence of *complex* matrices, the answer is known (see the survey paper in the linked thread or Horn and Sergeichuk's papers mentioned in that survey paper), but I'm not sure about the real case, although in some special cases (e.g. when the symmetric parts of $A$ and $B$ are both positive definite, both negative definite or both zero) there are easy answers.

Comment: Thank you so much.@user1551

Comment: Where do we run into congruence? It's the change-of-basis relation for quadratic forms. The textbook theorem only deals with symmetric matrices because we only care about congruence for symmetric (or Hermitian, over $\mathbb{C}$) matrices.